# Using Count sort to sort a given array

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

This is the code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
       int input[20],output[20],n,i,element,max;
       printf("Enter the no of elements");
       scanf("%d ",&n);
       for(i = 1;i<=n;i++){
         scanf("%d",&input[i]);
       }
       max = input[1];
    
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
         if(max<input[i]){
            max = input[i];
         }
       } 
    
      int c[max + 1];
      memset(c,0,sizeof(c));

      for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
         c[input[i]]++ ;
      }
      for(i = 1;i<=max;i++){ 
        c[i] = c[i] + c[i-1];
      }
    
      for(i = 1;i<=max;i++){
        output[c[input[i]]] = input[i];
        c[input[i]]--;
      }         
      for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        input[i] = output[i];
      }
      for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", input[i]);
      }

      return 0;
}
```

This is working for some cases and not for some. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
For example :
Enter the no of elements:7
input:3 2 5 16 3 2
output: 1 4223016 2 3 3 5 2 (Doesn't work here)

Comment: Why are you skipping `input[0]` in this loop: `for(i = 1;i<=n;i++) { scanf("%d",&input[i]); }`?

Comment: Also consider your input , you enter no items is 7, and then as input 3 2 5 16 3 2, those are 6 numbers.

Comment: `c[input[i]]` might cause undefined behavior. Where `input[i]` might be larger than `max+1`. Unless you have restriction in input range.

Comment: C array indexing is zero-based.  Trying to start at index 1 is asking for problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is an inconsistency in your question. You provided `n=7` but passed only 6 numbers as input.

Secondly, there are couple of changes required in the implementation:

1. For the following snippet in your code:

   ```
   for(i = 1;i<=max;i++){
       output[c[input[i]]] = input[i];
       c[input[i]]--;
   }
   ```

The loop should go on from 1 to n: `for(i = 1;i<=n;i++)`

2. For the following snippet:

   ```
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
       input[i] = output[i];
   }
   ```

The loop should go on from 1 to n: `for(i = 1;i<=n;i++)`.

Have a look at the following correct implementation:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int input[20],output[20],n,i,element,max;
    
    printf("Enter the no of elements");
    scanf("%d ",&n);
    
        for(i = 1;i<=n;i++){
            scanf("%d",&input[i]);
        }
    
    max = input[1];
    
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if(max<input[i]){
                max = input[i];
            }
        }     
    
    int c[max + 1];

    memset(c,0,sizeof(c));

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        c[input[i]]++ ;
    }

    for(i = 1;i<=max;i++){ 
        c[i] = c[i] + c[i-1];
    }

    for(i = 1;i<=n;i++){
        output[c[input[i]]] = input[i];
        c[input[i]]--;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        input[i] = output[i];
    }
    
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", input[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**INPUT:**

```
7
3 2 5 16 3 2 8000
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2 2 3 3 5 16 8000
```

**PS:** This algorithm won't work for negative numbers. You can give it a thought on how to handle negative numbers.